# how to stop sudo requirement for specific folders

Tags: permissions

I have `EACCESS ERROR` from npm due to permissions, I've already changed the global installation location for packages, yet some packages perform actions in installation such as `mkdir` where they fail the whole installation.
Any way I can remove sudo prefix requirement in var/www completely for stuff that don't really need elevation?

Comment: This is a bad idea, but chmod 777

Comment: Deb packages expect to install files to multiple locations in the filesystem. Your idea to move the "global installation location for packages" is the root of this problem. Disabling permissions is a cure worse than the disease. DON'T do it. Instead, solve the space problem that led you to haywire your system in the first place.